# Any way to migrate AWS T3 x64 to T4G ARM?

Tags: linux, upgrade, amazon-linux, cpu-architecture, arm

Is there any easy way to migrate from **aws x64 to arm** arch? like without configuring a new arm based server and installing packages and file? it is currently running with Amazon linux AMI, we wish to change it to Amazon linux AMI 2.

I just wanna know if there is some **tool/method** to proceed with this.

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to do if you want you create an AMI and launch a new instance using it or take a snapshot question was not really clear to be honest

Comment: I have a t3 x64 machine with Amazon linux 1 . I want to upgrade that to a t4g ARM. What i want to know is, whether there is some way to Upgrade from t3 x64 -> t4g ARM, without having to setup everything manually. does that help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that. X86 code doesn't run natively on ARM, nor vice versa. You must create a new instance and migrate any data you wish to migrate.

Comment: thanks. just wanted to see if there was any other way